# Browser (HTTP client) with support of bzip2 or lzma2 compression?

Tags: compression, browser, http, apache-httpd, lighttpd

What browsers (HTTP clients) support HTTP compression using bzip2 or lzma2? (HTTP compression for page requests)

I have only heard of Firefox patch, but I am not sure if it actually supports compression on page requests.
https://wiki.mozilla.org/LZMA2_Compression

Answer (score 1):

Yes, supports compression on "page requests", which are part of "content" in the context of transfer encoding. From the linked article,

> This patch allows Firefox to accept content from a web server which is
>   compressed using the LZMA2 compression algorithm...